# Adding button click counter in rails 3

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I want to add buttons on my article so that I can know the number of times its clicked and update counter on the database, I am using mongoid ,my model is:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :title, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String
  field :likes, :type => Integer ,:default => 0
  field :dislikes, :type =>Integer, :default => 0
  field :spam, :type => Integer, :default => 0
end
```

My articles show controller is:

```
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @article }
    end
  end
```

My View for show is:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= raw @article.content %>
</p>

Likes : <%= @article.likes %>  <br/>
Dislikes : <%= @article.dislikes %><br/>
Spams : <%= @article.spam %><br/>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

I find anything about it in internet.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be add a `click_count` integer attribute to your `Article` model and then increment this in your controller code:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.increment! :click_count

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @article }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it done, phew!

I added the following form in my show.html.erb:

```
<%=form_for(@article,:action=>"update") do |f| %>
<%= submit_tag "Like", :name=>"like"%>
<%= submit_tag "Dislike",:name=>"dislike"%>
<%= submit_tag "Spam",:name=>"spam" %>
<%end%>
```

and wrote the following update controller:

```
def update
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    if params[:like]
      @article.likes=@article.likes+1
    elsif params[:dislike]
      @article.dislikes=@article.dislikes+1
    elsif params[:spam]
      @article.spams=@article.spams+1
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        format.html {redirect_to @article, :notice => "Article Updated"}
      else
        format.html {render :action=>"edit", :notice=> "Unable to update Article , sorry! :("}
      end
    end
  end
```

It worked like a charm.