# Cleanly increment! attribute on model when user clicks on a link_to image_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an **Advert** model that basically has an image, title and a url. I use CarrierWave for the image. Everything works well, but I am wanting to count **impressions** and **clicks**.

---

**So far, I added two integer columns:** impressions, clicks

I have a **pages** controller and have set an **@advert** variable that changes depending on the page. After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681355/adding-button-click-counter-in-rails-3) I am able to increment impressions:

```
 def index  
   @advert = Advert.sample  
   @advert.increment! :impressions  
 end
```

---

**I am having trouble incrementing the clicks** | Below is the code I need to modify so that when a user clicks on the image_tag they are taken to the URL as normal, but that the @advert increments the **clicks** column. Here is my current code (I use HAML and this is code is in a file: _advert.html.haml):

```
  = link_to image_tag("#{advert.foto_url.to_s}",:alt => "an image ad linking to #{advert.url}", :title => advert.title), advert.url, :target => "blank"
```

---

What is the easiest, cleanest way to successfully increment! the **clicks** attribute on the Advert when someone clicks on the link above?

#### Update:

I am using the suggestion from Aaron below, but it leads to two new concerns:

- The user will see a different link when they hold their mouse over the image than the final link they will end up at. I would prefer to have them see the final URL they will end up if they click rather than Redirecting simply to count their click.
- If someone pulls up the advert url (eg: /adverts/1) directly the counter would increment! without a click.

I actually didn't have a show view for Advert, but added it to get this done. **So to be clear** this works, but it feels like it violates best practices. **Thank you though to Aaron.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to make the advert image link to the advert show action, which could increment the counter and then redirect to the advert url.

In your link, change `advert.url` to `advert_path(advert)` (and set up the necessary route) then in `adverts_controller`:

```
def show
  @advert = Advert.find(params[:id])
  @advert.increment! :clicks
  redirect_to @advert.url
end
```

Comment: Aaron. Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question with some concerns that I would have as a result of going through the show view and then redirecting the user.I also tweaked your suggestion, since I am trying to increment! :clicks.

Comment: If this turns out to be the best answer, I will happily give you the credit. I gave you a +1 for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks! You could add `:method => :post` to the `link_to` and then route `post '/adverts/:id => "adverts_controller#show' to fix the second problem. The first problem is harder, but if are okay with my solution, you could add a `title` attribute to the `link_to` with the url.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I think for as simple as my Advert model is and our needs, I can live with this solution. I have the :title set to show the advert.url when the mouse is over the image.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to mind was adding JavaScript so that when that link is clicked it asynchronously sends a request to your server then allows the link to go through as designed.

Comment: I assuming I would bind to the on-click event, just not sure how to do the rest. I still mostly suck at Javascript. :(

Comment: You could do the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124074/ruby-rails-ajax-jquery-on-link-click-passing-a-parameter-and-performing-a-con, just remove the preventDefault line and return true.